# Maximum number of adapters in PingFederate

Tags: pingfederate

I'm using HTMLFormIDP adapter in PingFederate IDP side. Each organization has their own adapter and `login` and `logoff` templates.

What would be the maximum number of adapters that can be created in PingFederate IDP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no known limit for the number of adapters PingFederate can support.

Note that if you're only changing login and logoff template values in each instance, we'd recommend you create a hierarchy of adapters, where the base (parent) one has the global settings you want to apply - and you create child instances from it that adjust the template values.

See: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=nxg1564002998160.html

Comment: Thanks Scott!!!. Unfortunately we are using PF6.10. believe optional field is an updated version.